# Will P&O demur if I turn up without a bicycle?

Tags: ferries

I have a Calais-Dover ferry ticket for 2 people with bikes.

Bizarrely, they were cheaper than foot passenger tickets.

Plans have changed, I'm now unable to take the bikes (going the other way on the eurostar). Will they refuse to let me on?

Comment: Curious - when you say bike do you mean bicycle or motorcycles?

Comment: Will they let you on, sure.  Will they require you to change your tickets to the correct category, maybe.

Comment: bicycle, pushbike, pedal cycle...

Comment: Take one or two of [these](https://www.unicycle.uk.com/12-tiniuni-unicycle.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2qrTqOPU1gIV7rvtCh1CXwNfEAQYASABEgLHPvD_BwE)

Comment: If you can find an old beater each, just good enough to ride a few more miles (or even just a few more meters, you can use your 'bicycle' tickets. Leave them in the port area at the other end, unlocked with a note: "Free, take me please", and you do not have to worry about what happens to them.

Comment: if the fare is that favorable, I should start a bicycle rental business at each port and take money to let people move my bicycles from port to port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [terms and conditions](http://www.poferries.com/en/terms-and-conditions) (emphasis mine):

> Changes in the route, date, time, passenger numbers or **vehicle types**
> for non-promotional fares are subject to availability and will result
> in the difference in price between the original price and the fare
> applicable on the day you make the amendment being charged (a
> “Re-price”) and an amendment fee as set out in the table in 4ii below.

You'd be charged (for the whole booking, not per person):

> £20 + Walk up fare (at least £95) - Amount already paid

However, the risk of this being enforced seems slim, but if they tried it on, you'd have no recourse other than to pay.